# Visual Studio 2010 and std::function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, functional-programming, c++11, functor

I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct A
{
    int operator()(int i) const {
        std::cout << "F: " << i << std::endl;
        return i + 1;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    std::tr1::function<int(int)> f = std::tr1::ref(a);
    std::cout << f(6) << std::endl;
}
```

The aim is to pass the functor object by a reference_wrapper, in a way to avoid useless copy costructor calls.
I expect the following output:

```
F: 6
7
```

It works correctly with GCC >= 4.4.0, Visual Studio 2008 and with boost by substituting std::tr1 namespace with boost. It only doesn't work with the new Visual Studio 2010 both Express Beta 2 and Release Candidate.

Are this new C++ features bugged in vs2010?
Or there is some mistake or misuse in the code?

Comment: @litb: I think the OP has problems with using the `std::tr1::ref` template class and *not* boost on VS2010.

Comment: Here is the build output of vs2010:

http://pastebin.com/YQf4Qe8W

Comment: More details:
The same code with included <boost/tr1/functional.hpp> instead of <functional> works with vs2008, but steel does not works with vs2010.
Tha built-in implementation of the <funtcional> header (and its deps) of vs2010 seems to support function call invocation of reference_wrapper objects... but it can't compile :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think i found the reason. This is what TR1 `3.4/2` says about `result_of<T(A1, A2, ..., AN)>::type`, used in the determination of the return type of `reference_wrapper<T>::operator()`:

> The implementation may determine the type member via any means that produces the exact type of the expression f(t1, t2, ..., tN) for the given types. [Note: The intent is that implementations are permitted to use special compiler hooks —end note]

And then paragraph 3:

> If F is not a function object defined by the standard library, and if either the implementation cannot determine the type of the expression f(t1, t2, ..., tN) or if the expression is ill-formed, the implementation shall use the following process to determine the type member:
>
> - If F is a possibly cv-qualified class type with no member named `result_type` or if `typename F::result_type` is not a type:
>
>   - If N=0 (no arguments), type is void.
>   - If N>0, type is `typename F::template result<F(T1, T2,..., TN)>::type`

The error message is an artefact of trying these fall-backs. Provide a typedef for `result_type` to `int` and it should work, i think. Notice that in `C++0x`, this is different. It does not rely on `result_type` or a `result` template, since it can use `decltype`.

If with `<functional>` it fails with MSVC10 in C++0x mode, it smells like a bug, i would say. But maybe someone else knows what's going on. It may (but is not guaranteed to) work with `<tr1/functional>` in C++0x mode if that header chooses to take the `decltype` way instead of `::result_type`. I would typedef `result_type` - that way i think it should always work regardless of whether the `tr1` header is used or the `c++0x` header.

---

Also notice that `boost::tr1` says in its documentation that it does not support the function call operator (but it merely supports implicit conversions to `T&`).

Comment: Yeah, this fix the problem :D 
It is a pity for vs2010 for this regression with respect to the previous 2008 version... Most recent draft strictly requires the compiler to be able to recognise the return type automatically.
http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2009/n3000.pdf
Paragraph 20.7.4

Answer (score 1):

I encounter a similar problem here :
[Prevent unnecessary copies of C++ functor objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216041/prevent-unnecessary-copies-of-c-functor-objects/2216928#2216928)

To make it compile on MSVC10, I had to derive my function object from std::unary_function.