# Compiler error C3493: 'func' cannot be implicitly captured because no default capture mode has been specified

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, c++11, compiler-errors

Can you help me resolve this compiler error?

```
template<class T>
static void ComputeGenericDropCount(function<void(Npc *, int)> func)
{
    T::ForEach([](T *what) {
        Npc *npc = Npc::Find(what->sourceId);

        if(npc)
            func(npc, what->itemCount); // <<<<<<< ERROR HERE
            // Error    1   error C3493: 'func' cannot be implicitly captured because no default capture mode has been specified

    });
}

static void PreComputeNStar()
{
     // ...
    ComputeGenericDropCount<DropSkinningNpcCount>([](Npc *npc, int i) { npc->nSkinned += i; });
    ComputeGenericDropCount<DropHerbGatheringNpcCount>([](Npc *npc, int i) { npc->nGathered += i; });
    ComputeGenericDropCount<DropMiningNpcCount>([](Npc *npc, int i) { npc->nMined += i; });
}
```

I can't understand why it's giving me the error and I don't know how to fix it. `ComputeGenericDropCount(auto func)` doesn't work either.

Comment: You may find this interesting:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425277/visual-studio-2010-and-stdfunction

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You need to specify how to capture `func` into the lambda.

`[]` don't capture anything

`[&]` capture-by-reference

`[=]` capture-by-value (copy)

```
T::ForEach([&](T *what) {
```

I'd also recommend that you should send `func` by const reference.

```
static void ComputeGenericDropCount(const function<void(Npc *, int)>& func)
```

Comment: This doesn't work and gives me the same error; also I thought that `[]` means "capture nothing"; `[&]` means "capture all upvalues by reference, `[*]` means "capture all upvalues by copy", and so on.. But I think this only affects how upvalues are captured, ie, it will only affect code *inside* the lambda

Comment: You need to capture func in-order to use it inside the lambda, which you do. I don't see how you could get the same error. I'll try it myself once i get home.

Comment: Sorry! I added the `&` to the wrong lambdas, the callbacks from `ComputeGenericDropCount`, instead of `ForEach`, as you said. Now everything makes sense: it needed to know how to capture func, of course!! Thanks again.

Comment: `&` is what I need. Thanks