# No matching call error occuring for boost::ref but not with std::ref

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-ref

I've written some code which counts the number of elements of vector using a functor and the `ref` and `bind` templates from `boost::` or `std::` (for C++11) namespaces. I'm using a `#define` to switch between `boost::` and `std::` namespaces. I'm using boost version 1.53  and my compilation command is `g++ test.cpp -std=c++11`. I've tried with gcc versions 4.7.2 and 4.6.3 and I get the same errors with both.

I have 3 questions:

1. I don't understand the error that is generated for Example 2.
2. Is it possible to make code like this portable just by switching namespaces?
3. Is there a good reference describing in detail the differences between the `std` and `boost` versions of `bind`, `ref` and `function`? (I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555566/is-there-any-difference-between-c11-stdbind-and-boostbind) question but the answers don't mention `ref` or `function`)

Thanks!

P.S. The example just illustrates my problem, I know about `size()` for `std::vector` :-)

```
//#define USE_STD

#ifdef USE_STD
#include <functional>
using namespace std::placeholders;
namespace impl = std;
#else
#include <boost/version.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/ref.hpp>
namespace impl = boost;
#endif

#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

class Item {
    int id_;

public:
    Item(int id) : id_(id) {};
};

template <typename ITEM>
class Counter {
    int count_;

public:
    // typedef void result_type; // adding this fixes Example 3 when impl=boost
    Counter() : count_(0) {};
    void operator()(ITEM* item) {count_++;}
    int operator()() {return count_;}
};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#ifndef USE_STD
    std::cout << "BOOST_LIB_VERSION=" << BOOST_LIB_VERSION << std::endl;
#endif

    // allocate
    typedef std::vector<Item*> ItemVec;
    ItemVec vec;
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {vec.push_back(new Item(i));}

    // Example 1, works for BOTH
    Counter<Item> f1;
    f1 = std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), f1);
    std::cout << "f1()=" << f1() << std::endl;

    // Example 2, works with impl=std ONLY
    // COMPILE ERROR with impl=boost: "no match for call to ‘(boost::reference_wrapper<Counter<Item> >) (Item*&)’"
    Counter<Item> f2;
    std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), impl::ref(f2));
    std::cout << "f2()=" <<  f2() << std::endl;

    // Example 3, works with impl=std ONLY
    // COMPILE ERROR with impl=boost "no type named ‘result_type’ in ‘class Counter<Item>’"
    // this can fixed by adding the typedef described above
    Counter<Item> f3;
    std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), impl::bind(impl::ref(f3), _1));
    std::cout << "f3()=" << f3() << std::endl;

    // clean up
    for (ItemVec::iterator it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it) {
        delete *it;
    }
    vec.clear();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example 2 fails because [`boost::reference_wrapper`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost/reference_wrapper.html) doesn't have a [member `operator()` which forwards the argument(s)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper/operator%28%29), unlike `std::reference_wrapper`. As such, it's only useful for passing normal arguments by reference, not functions or functors which are expected to be called.

Example 3 fails because Boost.Bind [relies on a specific protocol to get the result type of the function or functor you pass](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/bind/bind.html#with_function_objects), if you use the version without explicit return type. If you pass it a pointer-to-function or pointer-to-member-function, the returnd binder object has a nested `result_type` set to the return type of said PTF or PTMF. If you pass a functor, it needs a nested `result_type`.
`std::bind`, on the other hand, simply has no nested `result_type` if your functor doesn't have one.

Note that you can, as I said, explicitly provide the result type to both `boost::bind` and `std::bind`:

```
std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), impl::bind<void>(impl::ref(f3), _1));
//                                              ^^^^^^
```

Which fixes the example and makes it compile.

Comment: The code you provided works for me, I guess this is the only way to support both boost and std binds then. I'll read cppreference and the boost documentation more thoroughly to better understand the differences. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`std::ref` has 1 major advantage over `boost::ref`:  It provides a varadic perfect-forwarding `operator()`, which will forward the call onto its contained reference.

`boost::ref` can't practically do this, as it would require a significant number of overloads.  To allow this, however, `boost::bind` (and a few other classes) all provide special handling for `boost::reference_wrapper`.